# Gridview like display for hibernate objects in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, user-interface, web-applications, gridview

Essentially what I am looking for is a good way to build a quick database interface. In my (limited) experience with ASP.net I've used a Gridview control for this task. However for this project I am going to be using Java.

Can anyone recommend a good way to set up a Gridview like control (with editable and sortable rows) in a Java web framework? I was leaning towards using Spring MVC, but I am not particular attached to any Java web framework.

My data is pulled from a database using Hibernate, so any control that could plug directly into that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Server Faces (JSF) has a [dataTable](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/dataTable.shtml) component. If you combine that with a framework built on top of JSF such as [IceFaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/index.jsp) you will get sorting as well.

But if you're looking for a quick library to drop into a JSP, check out [displayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/). Doesn't handle editing of the data (should be easy enough to write some code for this anyway) but will handle paging and sorting.

Comment: Not having alot of luck plugging Hibernate POJ's into display tag.

Comment: I've used Hibernate POJOs before with displayTag without problems. Are you sure it's the Hibernate POJOs which is causing problems?

Comment: Yeah it's not so much an issue with display tag, its that display tags bring to the surface an exception that usually stays buried in the logs when I do an html output of the POJO.

Answer (score 1):

Tapestry 5 also has a grid view as well as good integration with Hibernate.  [This tutorial](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tutorial1/) shows you the basics.

Comment: Thanks, I think I may give Phill suggests a try first as they look to be a little more light weight.